# Change MovieClip size with input textbox (Flash AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a project where MovieClips can be dragged and dropped.

I would like to know how to make an input textbox appear after clicking on the
MovieClip, where the user is able to put in a number in the input textbox 
that increases the size of the MovieClip according to the number entered.

After the number is entered I would like the textbox to dissappear, 
and only reappear when MovieClip is clicked again.

Example illustration below:

[image: example]

Comment: okay, but what part are you stuck at? creating a dynamic textbox? listening to textbox changes? changing the movieclip size?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. The part I'm struggling with is: How do I make the textbox listen to changes, and make those changes modify the movieclip size. Essentially I know how to make a textbox but not how to apply code that changes movieclips size.

Comment: Do you have any code already? Set a mouse click event listener for the box and then make the text box appear once you click it. Then start another event listener for the Enter/Return key. Once you hit Enter, set the size of the square to the textbox value. Then remove the text box

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code I have does not really relate to my question specifically. How do I set the size of the square to the textbox value? Do you have an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, promptBox);


private function promptBox(e:MouseEvent)
{
    textBox.x = box.x;
    textBox.y = box.y - 25;
    addChild(textBox);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, resizeBox);
}

private function resizeBox(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(e.charCode == 13) //enter key
    {
        box.width = Number(textBox.text);
        box.height = Number(textBox.text);
        removeChild(textBox);
    }

}
```

Excuse me as I haven't used AS3 in a long time but this is the idea

Comment: First I got the error 1120: Access of undefined property event, so I tried changing "e:" to event, and then the error stopped showing but nothing seemed to change on stage. But I decided to try it once more and then it worked, thank you! I have to test it a bit more to be sure my answer has been answered.

Comment: @New2AS3 Sorry about that. `if(event.charCode == 13)` should be `if(e.charCode == 13)`. I changed the answer to the correct code

Comment: No problem. Other than the textbox moving slightly when clicking on it, the code works perfectly.